# Update pinned PFObject in Parse Local Storage from Parse Cloud

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

By `object.saveEventually()`, I will be able to sync my data in local storage with the cloud in Parse.

But here is what I am confused about, in the doc, it declares:

> When an object is pinned, every time you update it by fetching or
>   saving new data, the copy in the local datastore will be updated
>   automatically

But then, next example, few paragraphs away, unpins all objects then updates `HighScores` by pinning the new `scores` array with name `HighScores`

```swift
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query orderByDescending:@"score"];

// Query for new results from the network
[[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
  return [[PFObject unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithName:@"HighScores"] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *ignored) {
    // Cache the new results.
    NSArray *scores = task.result;
    return [PFObject pinAllInBackground:scores withName:@"HighScores"];
  }];
}];
```

Therefore, should I unpin all objects of `HighScores` in order to update existing scores in `HighScores`?

Will `findObjectsInBackground` automatically update any found object which is pinned? I am quite confused.

Thank you!

Comment: I did not unpin all objects and it still works.!!!

Comment: is it `findObjectsInBackground` or `fetchAllInBackground`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that both `findObjectsInBackground` and `fetchAllInBackground` will update any pinned object matching the `objectId`.

That is to say, when you create an object initially, it will not have an `objectId`, but you can still pin this object without successfully saving it. However, you can't `find` or `fetch` them until you successfully save it to the cloud. So in the code, you have to cherrypick these particular `PFObjects` out and update them some other ways or don't update them at all.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. 

If we can't fetch the object which was pinned in background, so what is the use of pinning at this time.

It would have been better, If we save to cloud first and then pin for viewing purpose only.